# Can Oracle ManagedDataAccess 4.122.1.0 connect to Oracle server 19c?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, oracle, driver, managed

We have a .NET MVC 5 application and several APIs using the Oracle ManagedDataAccess driver (version 4.122.1.0) to connect to a 12c Oracle server (version 12.1.0.2.0). We are about to upgrade to 19c. Will this version of the Oracle ManagedDataAccess driver connect to 19c or do I need to re-publish all of these apps with a newer driver?

Answer (score 0):

See [System Requirements](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-data-access-components/18.3/odpnt/InstallSystemRequirements.html#GUID-A6405CAD-C0E9-45E0-9C38-26B7ED214479)

> Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver requires the following:
>
> - Same Windows operating system support as ODP.NET, Unmanaged Driver.
>
>   ODP.NET, Managed Driver is built with AnyCPU. It runs on either 32-bit or 64-bit (x64) Windows and on either 32-bit or 64-bit (x64) .NET Framework.
> - Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2, 4.6.x, or 4.7.x.
> - Access to **Oracle Database 11g Release 2 or later**

So, no problem.

Comment: Unfortunately this is the UNmanaged data provider for 18c, not the managed provider for client 12c.

Comment: Then check https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/odpnt/InstallSystemRequirements.html#GUID-A6405CAD-C0E9-45E0-9C38-26B7ED214479 - it's the same: *Access to Oracle Database 10g Release 2 or later*. Or see https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=207303.1

Comment: That's still a requirement for a client version, how do we know it works all the way up to server 19?

Comment: The ManagedDataAccess  does not require any client, thus version requirement does not apply. Read it carefully! "*Access to Oracle Database 10g Release 2 or later*" means you need a database newer than version 10.2 - which is obviously true for version 19. Or read https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=726240.1 which shows even more detailed.

Comment: I misspoke, I meant the driver DLL file that this question is all about, but thank you for the correction. Saying the provider requires a 'database newer than 10.2' on the old provider docs may not be updated if 19c server connections, or newer, ever stop working. I think you are correct though, as I see a similar ORA driver is backwards compatible: https://docs.appeon.com/pb2019r2/connecting_to_your_database/ch11s01.html.